List item.Swipeable does not work in Modal
I have encountered this issue that ListItem.Swipeable doesn't work in a Modal (React Native). There's no error shown and the onBegin is not called upon swiping on the list item. I'm wondering if anyone has successfully implemented a List item.Swipeable in a Modal.
I have implemented ListItem.Swipeable both in a Modal and a Flat list within a Modal. Both don't work.
